# What do these statements mean and what happens when I change their values

Tags: actionscript-3

Still learning AS3. I would love to know more about these 2 simple statements.
My educated guess is movement or gravity on the x/y co-ords?

```
var dx:Number = x;
var dy:Number = x;
```

Much appreciation!

Comment: what two? `dx` and `dy`?

Comment: `dx` and `dy` are totally not used in your code snippet, I think no one would know what they are...maybe just some declared and not used variables.

Comment: The answer is simple: in the code you have provided, they serve no purpose at all. they're just 2 variables that both get whatever value `x` is at that time, but they are never used.

Comment: @user3564111 Why deleting all your code?

Answer (score 0):

So the code makes the character if jumping, move up at a gradually slower rate until it hits the ground again, where isJumping becomes false again. Each time the character jumps the isJumping is made true again and the cycle repeats (jumpPower is what controls how high). There is also gravity, which is also controlling how fast the jump falls.. however! I would like to point out a major flaw in this code..

jumpPower should not be controlling how fast he falls, gravity should. When jumpPower reaches zero, it then begins to fall into the negatives untill the character reaches the ground. This means that gravity + jumpPower will both be speeding the character to the ground.

I don't know if you meant to do this, but I would recommend having only gravity being the thing sending your character to the ground. A better way to code this would to give the character a velocity, which you apply to its x and y cords each enter frame.

Something like this..

```
velocityY += gravity;
MainChar.y += velocityY;
```

This way, when the character jumps, you only need to call this once:

```
velocityY += jumpPower;
```

...

Your code with velocity...

```
var dx:Number = x; // Not sure what these are
var dy:Number = x; // Not sure what these are

var velocityX:Number = 0;
var velocityY:Number = 0;

function doJump(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if(!isJumping) {
         jumpPower = -30;
         velocityY += jumpPower;
         isJumping = true;
     }
}

function update(evt:Event):void {
   if(MainChar.y + gravity < ground) {
       velocityY += gravity
       MainChar.y += velocityY;
   } else {
       velocityY = 0;
       MainChar.y = ground;
       isJumping = false;
   }
}
```

....

Final note. How come your MainChar is a static class?

I suppose the point is, not much can be answered about this question as I don't expect we have all of the code here.

Comment: Thank you very much, my main character is static and I have made a running animation and the background will be scrolling, an endless runner game :) I just have one small problem implementing the code, syntax error, "else" is unexpected.

Comment: I fixed it for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

On one hand you don't need to use these 2 variables `dx` and `dy`. On the contrary you forgot to declare the variables used in the code: `gravity`, `jumpPower`, `isJumping` and `ground`.

On the other hand it's better to use `enterFrame event` only when necessary and remove it at the end of the movement (in your function update).

At last you don't need to use your boolean variable `isJumping` (by actualising the value of your variable jumpPower = 30 at the end of your function update).

So your code should really be more simple:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, doJump);

const GRAVITY:int = 3;
var jumpPower:int = 0;
var ground:int = stage.stageHeight - MainChar.height;

function doJump(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}

function update(evt:Event):void {
    MainChar.y -= jumpPower;
    jumpPower -= 2;
    MainChar.y += GRAVITY;
    if(MainChar.y + GRAVITY > ground) {
       MainChar.y = ground;
       jumpPower = 30;
       removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }
}
```